# How can i set a default value for a missing argument inside void statement C++

Tags: c++, void

So, I have this code for example:

```
void doSomething(int aValue, int aValue2) {
    /*thigs to do...*/
}
int main() {
    doSomething(9);
}
```

Notice that I only used 9 for `aValue` and had `aValue2` empty.

What I want is to automatically fill-in the missing `aValue2` with a certain default value.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: not related, but functions should almost always return a value. otherwise, they must have side-effects, which is generally a bad thing.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Except for `main` which has special rules.

Comment: @NeilButterworth functions that neither return a value nor have side effects are not only allowed, they are considered extremely resource-efficient :)

Comment: @Cap main always returns a value, explicitly or implicitly

Comment: @Jer very funny

Comment: @NeilButterworth Correct. That's what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do it.  The first way is to declare your function with a default-argument, like this:

```
void doSomething(int aValue, int aValue2 = 123);
```

... then when it is called with only one argument, the compiler will treat the call as if the second argument was supplied as `123`.  Note that the default value goes in the line where the function is *declared*, not where it is *defined*, so in cases where you have a separate `.h` file containing the function's declaration, the `= 123` would go there and not in the `.cpp` file.

The other way would be to overload the function, like this:

```
 void doSomething(int aValue, int aValue2) {
     /*things to do...*/
 }

 void doSomething(int aValue) { 
     doSomething(aValue, 123);
 }
```

This is a little wordier, but it gives you more flexibility in deciding how the first (two-argument) version of the function should be called when the caller supplies only one argument.

Comment: It's worth noting that overloads are harder to form a pointer to. It's still possible, but it requires a disambiguated context, either by explicit `static_cast`, or by being used in something that explicitly takes a `void(*)(int)` or `void(*)(int,int)`. Contrast this to a default-value that makes `&doSomething` always produce a `void(*)(int, int)`

Answer (score 2):

What you want is known as a [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) where you assign the value to the parameter in the function declaration or definition if you do not have a forward declaration for the function. In the below example the default argument for `aValue2` is set to 100.

```
void doSomething(int aValue, int aValue2 = 100) {
    /*thigs to do...*/
}
int main() {
    doSomething(9);
}
```